# Effect of op-amp's input offset voltage on stability of constant current load

Tags: operational-amplifier, constant-current, input-offset-voltage

I'm designing a simple circuit to have a constant current load with good short term stability. The exact current value is not important, as long as it's stable short-term (10 seconds). R1 is the load - a nichrome heating element. The stability that I'm aiming at is *around* 2A of current stable to within +/- 0.5 mA.

I'm simulating it in LTSPICE. The voltage sources are all batteries so I'm expecting the voltages to stable short-term.
I've added resistance variation to the load to simulate the current variations that are happening in real life. I've also added resistance variation to the reference voltage divider resistors and the current source to simulate TCR (planning to use low TCR 25ppm resistors, simulating 2C short term variation).

My understanding is that the built-in op-amp model that I'm using doesn't account for the input offset voltage so I've added a 1mV voltage source (V4) in series with IN+ of the opamp.

I was expecting the offset voltage to result in a constant error in the current regulation but it worsened my precision 20 fold. So I'm wondering why this happened with the introduction of the *constant* input offset voltage.

I can use an ultra-low input offset voltage op-amp like LMP2021 and the offset voltage won't be an issue but just out of curiosity I'm wondering why this precision degradation is happening.

[LTSpice model download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1amZ8Zq8hQZhOE21yLYI0tKVXQYgGPXtz/view?usp=sharing)

LTSPICE model:

[image: LTSPICE simulation circuit]

Current without the offset voltage

[image: LTSPICE simulation current without the offset voltage]

Current with the 1mV offset voltage:

[image: LTSPICE simulation current with the 1mV offset voltage]

**Edit:** The voltage difference between IN+ and IN- looks is as follows:

[image: LTSPICE simulation: IN+ minus IN-]

Comment: What does the voltage at the + input of the op-amp look like?

Comment: @JohnD, added the graph to the question

Comment: Your value of R2 (23Ω), together with your value of V2 (47V), mean that V_DS of M2 is way too low to saturate.  2A times 23Ω is 46V, so you have only 1V "left" from V2 to power the MOSFET and the source-resistance drop (of 20mΩ * 2A = 40mV).  Try bumping V2 up 10V or so (to +57 instead of 47).

Comment: @Atomique, thanks! Lowered R1 to 22Ohm and it got rid of the big effect of the offset voltage. Still wonder why it was happening exactly, but understand this may not been easy to explain.

Comment: @axk This circuit works by comparing the voltage across R5 to some "desired value" which is at the + input of the opamp.  If the current thru R5 is too low, the opamp's output rises to "turn M2 on harder" to increase that current, and as such, keeps that current constant.  HOWEVER, M2 can't turn on the way you want it to if its V_DS is too low, because under that situation, it is effectively "already ON fully" i.e. its gate voltage really isn't doing very much -- M2 is more a very nonlinear resistor than a MOSFET.  When V_DS increases enough, the gate vs. the drain make M2 behave as it should.

Comment: @Atomique, I see, so this extra 1 mV was pushing the MOSFET just close enough to saturation that it was not enough to regulate the current with the required precision anymore, didn't think it was that close. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want constant heating power? If so, constant current may not be the correct choice as nichrome does have a change in resistance when heated.

Comment: @peufeu, I need the constant current source for calibrating a DIY e-bike power meter, need to dissipate all the power somehow thus the nichrome wire. The current through the wire is not very stable (TCR effect I suppose) thus the additional circuitry to stabilize it. I realize this is probably an overkill for an e-bike current meter (12 bit ADC), but I wonder how precise can a *simple* constant current load like this be made.

Comment: OK so the "power meter" actually measures current not power?

Comment: @peufeu, measures current and voltage (2 channel ADC) and then multiplies and accumulates to get power. Voltage is constant short term with no load so the voltage measurement is easy to calibrate just with a multimeter.